# Line Edit setText function Qt

Tags: c++, qt, rounding, settext

I have a `LineEdit` which I want it to present a `float` value. I want the `float` value to have 2 digits precision so I used number function like this:

```
float tax =  value * 0.23;
Qstring strTax = QString::number(tax, 'f', 2);
qDebug() << strTax;
ui->leTax->setText(strTax);
```

The thing is that while in console the value is printed with 2 digits precision, the widget prints all the decimal digits which might be 3 or more (depends on the value). Is there a way to fix it? I am using Qt 5.0.

Comment: How about showing the actual code that compiles and runs? There is no way that the QLineEdit would add some additional digits. There is a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: As Roku said above. Please post the code that you actually compile and run. The code you posted above does not even compile (Qstring with a non-capitalized s will give you a compile-time error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the accepted answer. I finally solved my problem. The `onTextUpdate` had to update two more `LineEdits` one containing the Tax and one containing The total amount. But the one containing the `totalAmount` also emitted the `onTextChanged` to update the net value and the Tax `LineEdits`, without rounding the values(I Was careless!!). So I corrected the `totalAmount`'s `onTextChanged`. I also updated it to check if it has focus so to know if it is its turn to update the other `LineEdits` or not :). The point was that someone could edit the `netValue` line edit and that would update the tax and total amount or someone would enter the `totalAmount` and that automatically would update the net Amount and tax field. Everything working now. Thank you all for answering!!

Comment: TL;DR: This question doesn't provide the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`setValidator` might be your solution.  Click [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qlineedit.html#setValidator) and [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qdoublevalidator.html#details)

```
void QLineEdit::setValidator ( const QValidator * v )
```

*Sets this line edit to only accept input that the validator, v, will accept. This allows you to place any arbitrary constraints on the text which may be entered.*

Also,  Set the number of decimal places with `setDecimals()`.

So, it should looks like this :

```
// bottom (-999.0), top (999.0), decimals (2)
lineEdit->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(-999.0, 999.0, 2, lineEdit));
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer....but it didn't work. This is how i did it:

    float fpa = value * 0.23;
    QString lnvalue = QString::number(fpa, 'f', 2);
    ui->leTax->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(-999.0, 999.0, 2, ui->leTax));
    ui->leTax->setText(QString::number(fpa));

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a float-version for QString::number(), so maybe try cast-to-double

```
ui->leTax->setText(QString::number((double)tax, 'f', 2));
```

But since qDebug() is already showing the correct value, you probably change your strTax somewhere else in the code.